# Routing is not going to the post part of the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

I can´t get into the HttpPost part of the controller.

I´ve created another controller and the problem is the same

I was working fine before

I´ve added tags [Route("CrearSolicitud")]
        [HttpPost, ActionName("CrearSolicitud")]

I´ve haven´t added anything to the routing part

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It goes to http://localhost:55935/Solicitudes
instead of http://localhost:55935/Solicitudes/CrearSolicitud

```
public class SolicitudesController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Solicitudes
        public ActionResult Index() 
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Get
        public ActionResult Solicitud()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Post        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Solicitud(Solicitudes s)
        {
            s.Id = "e17cba68-0a0b-4d6e-abaf-8026cb91fcd1";
            s.fk_tipo_transaccion = 3;
            s.fk_estado_solicitud = 1;
            db.Solicitudes.Add(s);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

The view

```
@model HGRecursosHumanos4.Models.Solicitudes

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (@Html.BeginForm("CrearSolicitud", "Solicitudes", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VacacionesDias, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VacacionesDias, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VacacionesDias, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="date" id="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" class="Filtros form-control input-sm" />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Solicitar" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

When I use the form and hit the submit button or the application goes to Index or to the same view again

It´s like EF went broke or something

I´ve added that, an error comes out The 'CrearSolicitud' view or its master view is not found or there is no search engine that supports the search locations. We searched in the following locations:

```
~/Views/Solicitudes/CrearSolicitud.aspx
~/Views/Solicitudes/CrearSolicitud.ascx
~/Views/Shared/CrearSolicitud.aspx
~/Views/Shared/CrearSolicitud.ascx
~/Views/Solicitudes/CrearSolicitud.cshtml
~/Views/Solicitudes/CrearSolicitud.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/CrearSolicitud.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/CrearSolicitud.vbhtml 

@Nemanja      I certainly don´t have that view, if I use the same name on the post and no the get, the application goes to the get part again
```

Comment: can we see the return statement of this action method: CrearSolicitud?
Are you trying to browse this URl directly: http://localhost:55935/Solicitudes/CrearSolicitud?
The view you have renders on calling which action method?

Comment: I´m going to edit

Comment: Decorate the the first action with [HttpGet], so it wont accept post request. Now with the same name, request will go to desired action. Also, this view you have above comes up for which action 'Index'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution.

The thing is, index is for showing a list of added registries, when it is changed for something else you can´t see that list and that leads you to wrong conclusions.

The routing is working fine, the program is doing what is supposed to do, the RedirectToAction("Index") is ok.

The lesson is, take a while and think about what are you changing and try to follow the VS way of doing things.

I´ve tested now and it´s working

```
 ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            // GET: Solicitudes
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult Index2()
            {
                return View(db.Solicitudes.ToList());
            }

            //Get
            public ActionResult Solicitud()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Solicitud(Solicitudes s)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {                 

                        s.FechaFinal = DateTime.Now;
                        s.FechaYHoraSolicitud = DateTime.Now;
                        s.Id = "e17cba68-0a0b-4d6e-abaf-8026cb91fcd1";
                        s.fk_tipo_transaccion = 3;
                        s.fk_estado_solicitud = 1;
                        db.Solicitudes.Add(s);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.Message = "Solicitud guardada";
                        ModelState.Clear();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index2");
                    }
                    return View("ModelStateError");
                }
                //catch
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //throw ex;
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
```